# Meteor returning NaN in the browser

Tags: javascript, meteor, nan

I'm building a simple ordering app in Meteor and have come a cropper trying to get the order total even though I can get it to log in the console as a bona fide number - it is being rendered as NaN. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note the totals of individual products are appearing fine.

I have the following files:

meteorder/client/templates/orders/order_build.js:

```
Template.order.helpers({
'orderitems': function() {
    var orderCart = [];
    var orderItems = OrderItems.find({});
    var total = 0;

    orderItems.forEach(function(orderItem) {
        var item = _.extend(orderItem, {});
        var product = Products.findOne({
            _id: orderItem.product
        });
        orderItem.productname = product.description;
        orderItem.price = (Number(product.price) * orderItem.qty);
        total += orderItem.price;
        orderCart.push(orderItem);
    });

    orderCart.subtotal = total;
    orderCart.tax = orderCart.subtotal * .23;
    orderCart.total = orderCart.subtotal + orderCart.tax;
    return orderCart;

}
})
```

meteorder/client/templates/orders/order_build.html:

```
<template name="order">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>
            <small>My Order</small>
        </h1>
    </div>
    <table class="span4 table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
        <th>Qty</th>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th></th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {{#each orderitems}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{qty}}</td>
            <td>{{productname}}</td>
            <td>{{currency price}}</td>
            <td><span class="label-important label removeci">X</span></td>
        </tr>
        {{else}}
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">No Products in Order</td>
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
        <tr>
            <td class="totalcol" colspan="2">SubTotal:</td>
            <td colspan="2">{{currency orderCart.subtotal}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="totalcol" colspan="2">Tax 6%:</td>
            <td colspan="2">{{currency orderCart.tax}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="totalcol" colspan="2">Total:</td>
            <td colspan="2">{{currency orderCart.total}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</template>
```

meteorder/client/lib/main.js:

```
Template.registerHelper('currency', function(num){
  return '€' + Number(num).toFixed(2);
});
```

meteorder/server/server.js:

```
Meteor.methods({

addToOrder:function(qty,product,session){
    check(qty, Number);
    check(product, String);
    check(session, String);
    if(qty > 0){
        OrderItems.insert({qty:qty,product:product,sessid:session});
        console.log('reaching this fn', typeof qty, typeof product,      typeof session);

    } else{
        console.log('Quantity is Zero');
    }

},
removeOrderItem:function(id){
     check(id, String);
    OrderItems.remove({_id:id});
    console.log('successfully deleted');
}
});
```

Here is a link to the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/brianjlennon/meteorder2)

And the latest version of the [deployed App](http://meteorder.meteor.com/)

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

Just adding this in for Matthias:

```
    Template.productItem.events({
'click .addOrder':function(evt,tmpl){
  var qty1 = tmpl.find('.prodqty').value;
  var qty = parseInt(qty1);
    var product = this._id;
    var sessid = Meteor.default_connection._lastSessionId; //stops others  adding to your cart etc

    Meteor.call('addToOrder',qty, product, sessid);
     console.log('this is the quantity:', typeof qty, product, sessid);//stops others  ad
}
});
```

to see if it gives a better picture of why the cart is not populating. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use `orderCart` as both an array of objects and an object. You push a bunch of `orderItem` objects on to the array but at the end you attempt to set `orderCart.subtotal` etc...

Change your helper to have a separate summary object:

```
var summary = {};
summary.subtotal = total;
summary.tax = summary.subtotal * .23;
summary.total = summary.subtotal + summary.tax;
return {items: orderCart, summary: summary}
```

Then in your html do:

```
{{#each orderitems.items}}
...
{{/each}}
```

Finally in your summary line use `{{currency orderitems.summary.tax}}` etc...

Comment: Thanks a million! Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Your values are rendered as `NaN` because `orderCart` is `undefined`.

You could define a separate helper to fix your code:

```
Template.order.helpers({
    orderItems: function () {
        return OrderItems.find().map((orderItem) => {
            let product = Products.findOne({
                _id: orderItem.product
            });
            if (product) {
                orderItem.productname = product.description;
                orderItem.price = calcPrice(product, orderItem);
                return orderItem;
            }
        });
    },
    orderCart: function () {
        let orderCart = {subtotal: 0};
        OrderItems.find().forEach((orderItem) => {
            let product = Products.findOne({
                _id: orderItem.product
            });
            if (product) orderCart.subtotal += calcPrice(product, orderItem);
        });
        orderCart.tax = orderCart.subtotal * .23;
        orderCart.total = orderCart.subtotal + orderCart.tax;
        return orderCart;
    }
});

function calcPrice(product, orderItem) {
    return (Number(product.price) * orderItem.qty);
}
```

---

```
<template name="order">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>
            <small>My Order</small>
        </h1>
    </div>
    <table class="span4 table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
        <th>Qty</th>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th></th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {{#each orderItems}}
            <tr>
                <td>{{qty}}</td>
                <td>{{productname}}</td>
                <td>{{currency price}}</td>
                <td><span class="label-important label removeci">X</span></td>
            </tr>
        {{else}}
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">No Products in Order</td>
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
        {{#with orderCart}}
            <tr>
                <td class="totalcol" colspan="2">SubTotal:</td>
                <td colspan="2">{{currency orderCart.subtotal}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="totalcol" colspan="2">Tax 6%:</td>
                <td colspan="2">{{currency orderCart.tax}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="totalcol" colspan="2">Total:</td>
                <td colspan="2">{{currency orderCart.total}}</td>
            </tr>
        {{/with}}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</template>
```

**Please note:** I noticed a lot of missing semicolons. I strongly recommend to fix that, as this may cause several issues on deployment due to Meteor's minifying process.

Comment: Hi Matthias. Thanks for your response. You code gets the subtotal/total part of the order working perfectly but for some reason when I click the Add to order button the products list remains blank even though the totals are all there. It's like the `addToOrder` method is not being called at all. I will paste the event above if I can. I really liked your solution so would love to nail it this way. Thanks.

Comment: PS I will definitely take that onboard re: semi-colons! Thanks!

Comment: I am sorry, but I cannot reproduce your issue. Could you please make a temporary branch and share your code?

Comment: Thanks matthias. Here is the [GitHub branch] (https://github.com/BrianJLennon/METEORDER2/tree/temporary_METEORDER)

Comment: Please see my [pull request on GitHub](https://github.com/BrianJLennon/METEORDER2/pull/1).

Comment: Awesome Matthias! That works great! Really appreciate the help! Thank you!